# How to wait in WinForms application for X seconds without the UI freezing?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have this code, but the API has limited requests per minute, so I sometimes get error 429.
I need to wait about a minute, but the WinForm UI becomes unresponsive (I guess I'm stopping thread with UI doing this?). What would be the proper way to implement this?

Code:

```
public static int sleepTime { get; set; } = 60000;


public static string GetData(string URL)
{
    while (true) {
        try
        {
            Controller.SetAppStatus(AppStatusses.FetchingData);
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL);
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
            string rt = reader.ReadToEnd();
            return rt;
        }
        catch 
        {
            Controller.SetAppStatus(AppStatusses.Timeout);
            Timeout();
        }
    }
}

public static async void Timeout() {
    await Task.Delay(sleepTime);
}
```

Comment: Timeout should be `public static Task Timeout() { return Task.Delay(sleepTime); }` and be awaited when called: `await Timeout();`. This would require GetData to be declared as `public static Task<string> GetData(string URL)` and of course also be awaited.

Comment: Besides that, consider making an async web requests, e.g. by [`HttpClient.GetStreamAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.getstreamasync?view=netcore-3.1)

Comment: Yes agree Clemens.. having a receiver *event* is more convenient anyway.. On above code and the question: @Deramkol in Winforms, check out Application.DoEvents(). It will hand over control to the Windows message loop once, to allow for UI events. But keep in mind this strategy is *unsafe*. And I've also another note on your tight loop: it may become endless on *any* exception, not only timeout exceptions.. resulting in unawaited behaviour on e.g. remote disconnect. Asynchronous I/O provides events for that, so exceptions won't be needed.

Answer (score 0):

Use `HttpClient` class : [ms docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netframework-4.7.2), its the recommended way of issuing requests and it has `async` methods so you can make your logic asynchronous and you won't block the UI thread. In addition, you have to `await` the `Timeout` method and return a `Task` from it so no blocking would happen.